# How to not update null value into a column when it already have a value in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, mule, mule-component

How can I not update the null value into a column when it already have a value in SQL Server query in the query prepared in Mule? The payload contains the result set from Data weave. While updating, I want to check whether the updating value is null or not, in case of it "not null" then only value should be updated.

Query is:

```
UPDATE dbo.ix_str_store 
SET NAME = '#[payload.Site.Name]', 
    ADDRESS1 = '#[payload.Site.Address1]',
    ADDRESS2 = '#[payload.Site.Address2]',
    ADDRESSCITY = '#[payload.Site.AddressCity]',
    ADDRESSSTATE = '#[payload.Site.AddressState]',
    ADDRESSPOSTALCODE = '#[payload.Site.AddressPostalCode]', 
    ADDRESSCOUNTRY = '#[payload.Site.AddressCountry]', 
    EMAIL = '#[payload.Site.Email]', 
    PHONE = '#[payload.Site.Phone]', 
    FAX = '#[payload.Site.Fax]', 
    REGION = '#[payload.Site.Region]', 
    COMPANY = '#[payload.Site.Company]', 
    DESC1 = '#[payload.Site.Desc1]', 
    DESC2 = '#[payload.Site.Desc2]',
    DESC7 = '#[payload.Site.Desc7]',
    DESC8 = '#[payload.Site.Desc8]',
    VALUE1 = #[payload.Site.Value1], 
    VALUE2 = #[payload.Site.Value2], 
    DBTIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    DBSTATUS = 1 
WHERE 
    STORENUMBER = #[payload.Site.StoreNumber]
```

Answer (score 1):

try it's

```
isnull(new_value,old_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, instead of using `insert into (...) values(...)` construct ; use `insert into .. select from` construct like

```
insert into table (..)
select ..,
case when new_col_val is not null then new_col_val else old_col_val end
from ...
```

(OR) you can as well use `COALESCE()` function instead of `CASE` expression saying `coalesce(new_col_val, old_col_val)`